# Одновременный запуск нескольких потоков в PySide2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

При попытке, во время работы одного потока запустить другой, получаю ошибку `QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running`.

Сначала я думал, что для всех потоков можно создать один класс `Threads` и использовать разные функции, но теперь во время запуска одного потока, нарушается работа другого и приложение вылетает с ошибкой `QThread`, получается нужно создавать много классов?

Вообще в дальнейшем задумывалось, что пользователь будет выбирать нужное кол-во поток для выполнения определенной задачи, но как это сделать я же не могу заранее создать столько классов или функций. С ООП и PySide работаю недавно, поэтому извините если вопрос покажется очень глупым.

Мой код:

```
import random
import colorama
import time
import os
import sys
import design
import pyperclip
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class Threads(QtCore.QObject):
    running = False
    downloadCodesReady = QtCore.Signal(str)
    generateCodesReady = QtCore.Signal(int, int, str)
    myvar = None

    def __init__(self, myvar, parent=None):
        self.myvar = myvar
        super().__init__()

    def downloadCodes(self):
        countCodes = 0
        with open(self.myvar, 'r') as f:
            line = f.readline()
            while line:
                codes.append(line)
                countCodes = countCodes + 1
                line = f.readline()
        self.downloadCodesReady.emit(str(countCodes))

    def generateCodes(self):
        result = ''
        str1 = '123456789'
        str2 = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'
        str2 = str2.upper()
        str3 = str1+str2
        ls = list(str3)
        random.shuffle(ls)
        i = 0
        while i<self.myvar:
            if i==0:
                result = result+''.join([random.choice(ls) for x in range(20)])
            result = result+"\n"+''.join([random.choice(ls) for x in range(20)])
            i = i+1
            if (100/(self.myvar/i)).is_integer():
                self.generateCodesReady.emit(self.myvar, i, result)

class WarGenApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_Form):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.downloadCodesButton.clicked.connect(self.downloadCodes)
        self.startGenerateButton.clicked.connect(self.generateCodes)
        self.copyCodesButton.clicked.connect(self.copyGeneratedCodes)
        self.saveCodesInFileButton.clicked.connect(self.saveCodesInFile)

    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def downloadCodesReady(self, countCodes):
        self.countCodesLabel.setText(countCodes)
        self.thread.quit()

    @QtCore.Slot(int, int, str)
    def generateCodesReady(self, myvar, i, codes):
        self.progressCodesGenerationLabel.setText(f'{i}/{myvar}')
        self.generateCodesProgressBar.setValue(100/(myvar/i))
        if(i == myvar):
            self.generatedCodesText.setPlainText(codes)
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, "Инфо", "Пин-коды успешно сгенерированы!")
        self.thread.quit()

    def downloadCodes(self):
        fname = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Открыть файл', '', 'Text files (*.txt)')[0]
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.Threads = Threads(myvar=fname)
        self.Threads.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.Threads.downloadCodesReady.connect(self.downloadCodesReady)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.Threads.downloadCodes)

    def generateCodes(self):
        count = self.countCodesSpin.value()
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.Threads = Threads(myvar=count)
        self.Threads.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.Threads.generateCodesReady.connect(self.generateCodesReady)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.Threads.generateCodes)
        self.thread.start()

    def copyGeneratedCodes(self):
        pyperclip.copy(self.generatedCodesText.toPlainText())
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, "Инфо", "Пин-коды скопированы в буфер обмена!")

    def saveCodesInFile(self):
        fname = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Открыть файл', '', 'Text files (*.txt)')[0]
        try:
            with open(fname, 'w') as f:
                f.write(self.generatedCodesText.toPlainText())
        except Exception as e:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(self, "Ошибка", e)
        else:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, "Инфо", "Пин-коды успешно записаны в файл!")


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = WarGenApp()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

design.py
https://pastebin.com/erLTTHWH

Comment: Сложно понять ваше описание, код тоже замысловат. Вы бы просто описали свою задачу

Comment: Один поток одна задача

Comment: @Александр то есть нужен новый класс?

Comment: Ну да  в принципе, просто опишите словами что вы хотите сделать, может и одного потока будет достаточно

Comment: опубликуйте модуль `design.py`

Comment: @S. Nick https://pastebin.com/erLTTHWH

Comment: @Александр нужна многозадачность, чтобы GUI не зависал при выполнении каких-то задач, но запустить больше одного потока одновременно не получается

Comment: Какие действия надо выполнить чтобы получить ошибку, о которой вы пишите ?

Comment: Если многозадачность то для каждой задачи создайте поток и желательно наследовать QThread

Comment: @S. Nick на вкладке генератор запустите генерацию на 100000 кодов, и в это время на вкладке валидатор нажмите пин-коды и выберите какой-нибудь файл

Comment: попробуйте заменить строку `self.thread = QtCore.QThread()`  на `self.thread = QtCore.QThread(self)`

Comment: @S. Nick теперь все работает. Большое спасибо. Весь день пытался понять, что не так, в интернете почему-то мало информации про это.

Comment: пожалуйста, вы просто еще не научились искать. Искать надо так https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpyqt5%5D+or+%5Bpyside2%5D+QThread%3A+Destroyed+while+thread+is+still+running

Answer (score 0):

*Типо так*

Для каждой задачи отдельный поток

```
class DownloadCodesTask(QThread):
    my_signal = Signal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def run(self):
        # Ваш код
        string = "DownloadCodesTask"
        self.my_signal.emit(string)
class GenerateCodesTask(QThread):
    pass

class WarGenApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_Form):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.downloadCodesButton.clicked.connect(self.download_codes_start)

        self.download_codes_task = DownloadCodesTask()
        self.download_codes_task.my_signal.connect(self.download_codes_handler)

    def download_codes_start(self):
        #Запуск потока
        self.download_codes_task.start()
    Slot(str)
    def download_codes_handler(self, string):
        #Обработка сигнала
        print(string)
```

Comment: а можно запустить, например, 10 таких потоков одновременно? Если да, то как?

Comment: Зачем вам десять потоков если в работаете с одним объектом?

Comment: Как вообще будет проходить валидация ?

Comment: У вас генерация долго происходит или что?

Comment: с генерацией все в порядке. Валидация будет через selenium, поэтому чтобы ускорить процесс хотелось бы делать это многопоточно

Comment: Покажите код design.py

Comment: design.py https://pastebin.com/erLTTHWH